# Can you make photons without momentum?

Tags: photons, momentum, wavelength

What would it take to make photons without momentum? How would they behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum of a photon is given by:

$$ p = \frac{h}{\lambda} $$

so all photons have a momentum and there is no way to make the momentum zero. You can make the momentum arbitrarily small by making the wavelength $\lambda$ arbitrarily large, but the momentum can never become zero.

Comment: Wouldn’t momentum be zero if the wavelength was universe sized?

Comment: @Euphorbium The momentum would be very small, but it wouldn't be zero.